# how can i differentiate page load and onclick querystrings in omniture,chartbeat,foresee

Tags: adobe-analytics, chartbeat

I am using currently fiddler and firebug tools to get the requests and responses for my webpage load and click events. I am getting results, but how can differentiate the query string is for page load or for click event.

I want this process for site catalyst, chart beat and for foresee

Answer (score 3):

link click events will at a minimum have a `pe` query param, which gives the link type. It should have a value like `lnk_o` or `lnk_d` or `lnk_e`.  It may also have a `pev`, `pev1` or `pev2` query param which specifies the link name if you specified the 3rd argument in your `s.tl` call. Regular page view calls (`s.t` calls) do not have either of these parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Grab the firefox extension Omnibug. It will tell you the fired events and distinguish between page load, click and previous page click events. Omnibug will show you the Omniture and GA events but not Foresee or Chartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the official answer is a Link Track­ing request will have a “pe=” parameter in the image request. Page views will not.